# Creating a n-ary tree

Tags: c++, vector, tree

I am trying to create a n-ary tree with a vector of the children.

This is what I have gotten so far.

In the node.h file I have this:

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <string>

  using namespace std;

  class Node{

  private:
      Node *parent; 
      vector <Node*> children; 

      int data; 

  public: 
      Node();
      Node(Node parent, vector<Node> children);
      Node(Node parent, vector<Node> children, int data);

      Node * GetParent(); 

      void SetChildren(vector<Node> children);
      vector<Node>* GetChildren();
      void AddChildren(Node children);

      void SetData(int data);
      int GetData();

      bool IsLeaf();
      bool IsInternalNode();
      bool IsRoot();

  };
```

And this is my node.cpp file.

```
   #include "node.h"

   Node::Node(){
       this->parent = NULL; 
       this->children = NULL; 
       this->data = 0;
   }

   Node::Node(Node parent, vector<Node> children){
       this->parent = &parent; 
       this->children = &children; 
   }

   Node::Node(Node parent, vector<Node> children, int data){
       this->parent = &parent; 
       this->children = &children; 
       this->data = data; 
   }

   Node* Node:: GetParent(){
       return this->parent;
   }

   void Node::SetChildren(vector<Node> children){
       this->children = &children; 
   }

   vector<Node> * Node::GetChildren(){
       return this->children;
   }

   void Node::AddChildren(Node children){
       this->children.push_back(children);
   }

   void Node::SetData(int data){
       this->data = data;
   }
```

This obviously doesn't work. My main problem is that I am not quite sure how to handle the vector for the children. I wrote this following some tutorials online, but as you can see I am super confused.

Comment: The main error is that you are taking the address of a local variables. This will compile but it will crash when you run your program.

Comment: There a a multitude of things in here that are wrong, and have nothing to do with making a n-way tree. You're saving the address of temporary parameters in several places, for one.

Comment: Thanks for the replies ! I think i fixed that problem ! Now i have a problem with my GetChildren() function. I am allowed to do this->children? it doesnt look like I am

Answer (score 5):

The main (and possibly only) problem in your code is that you defined your `Node` class to manipulate nodes by pointers (`Node*`) :

```
class Node{
  private: 
    Node *parent; 
    vector <Node*> children;
```

But your methods are manipulating nodes by values (`Node`).

As instance, in the constructors :

```
Node::Node(Node parent, vector<Node> children){
    this->parent = &parent;
```

Storing the address of the *parent* parameter won't work, it's a temporary object, you'll need to pass a `Node* parent` to your constructor or to create a new *Node* object.

```
    this->children = &children;
```

This doesn't make any sense since `this->children` is a vector of `Node*` and the `children` parameter is a vector of `Node`. Again, you'll need to either pass a vector of `Node*` to your constructor or to create new node objects.

You have the same issues in `SetChildren` and `AddChildren`.

Also, since you're manipulating your nodes as pointers, **be very careful about the memory management**. There's no garbage collector in C++, you'll have to `delete` every thing you `new` and at the proper time.

Comment: @user2775084 Note that you have the same issue in both constructors but also in `SetChildren` and `AddChildren`.

Comment: @user2775084 That seems right, but you also have to do the same with `SetChildren` and `AddChildren`.

Comment: Thank you ! i think I fixed that problem. Now I am still having a problem with my GetChildren function. Since it is a vector, I am not quite sure I can do "return this->children."

Comment: @user2775084 You can return `this->children` as long as the return type of `GetChildren()` is `vector<Node*>` and not `vector<Node> *`. It will return a copy of the local vector but since it's a vector of pointers, the actual `Node` objects won't be copied.

Comment: OKay ! thank you so much ! you were really helpful. So do you think this looks like a good way to create the tree?

Comment: @user2775084 That's a very common way to build a tree in C++.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And for the reminder that I have to delete everything I new. I have one last question. In my Node(), i have this->children = NULL. That obviously doesnt work since NULL is not a vector. How could I set that vector as empty? I was trying this->children.empty(). Is that okay?

Comment: @user2775084 You don't have to assign `this->children` in the constructor, it's not a pointer, it's an object and it's already been created. You can use `this->children.empty()` but it would be useless in the constructor since the vector is already empty.

Answer (score 3):

Check if below code helps you to create n-array tree creation.

```
struct TreeNode
{
    vector<TreeNode*> children;
    char value;
};

class TreeDictionary
{
    TreeNode *root;
public:
    TreeDictionary()
    {
        root = new TreeNode();
        root->value = 0;
    }

    TreeNode *CreateNode(char data)
    {
        TreeNode *parent_node = new TreeNode;
        if (parent_node)
            parent_node->value = data;
        return parent_node;
    }
    TreeNode* SearchElement(TreeNode *NextNode, char *data, int& val)
    {
        bool bVal = false;
        for (vector<TreeNode*>::iterator it = NextNode->children.begin(); it != NextNode->children.end(); it++)
        {
            if ((*it)->value == *(data))
                return SearchElement((*it), ++data, ++val);
        }
        return NextNode;

    }
    TreeNode *InsertNode(TreeNode *parent, TreeNode *ChildNode, char data)
    {
        if (parent == NULL)
            ChildNode = CreateNode(data);
        else
        {
            TreeNode *childNode = CreateNode(data);
            parent->children.push_back(childNode);
            return childNode;
        }
        return ChildNode;
    }

    void InsertMyString(string str)
    {
        TreeNode *NextNode = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == '\0')
                return;
            cout << str[i] << endl;
            if (NextNode->value == 0)
            {
                NextNode->value = str[i];
                continue;
            }
            else if (NextNode->value != str[i])
            {
                NextNode = InsertNode(NextNode, NULL, str[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                TreeNode *node;
                node = SearchElement(NextNode, &str[++i], i);
                NextNode = InsertNode(node, NULL, str[i]);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    TreeDictionary td;
    td.InsertMyString("Monster");
    td.InsertMyString("Maid");
    td.InsertMyString("Monday");
    td.InsertMyString("Malli");
    td.InsertMyString("Moid");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of `SearchElement` (without recursion) also works:

```
TreeNode* SearchElement(TreeNode *NextNode, char *data, int& val)
{
    bool bVal = false;
    for (vector<TreeNode*>::iterator it = NextNode->children.begin(); it != NextNode->children.end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->value == *(data))
            return (*it);
    }
    return NextNode;
}

TreeNode* res = SearchElement(root, data, value);
```

I checked this out, not understandable, why - it works for any node you want to find in the tree, no matter the depth and the level of the node in the tree, And that's unclear why, Because the loop iterates only over the children at the second level of the tree (children of the root node), Despite this - it even will find nodes with depth of 10 levels in the tree.